# Nested scrollviewers with datagrids

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I have window with the next content:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="Outer" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="Inner1" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="700" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column A" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column B" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <TextBox Width="500" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="Inner2" Grid.Row="1" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column С" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column В" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

My goal is to make next:
if window content width is less than window width - outer horizontal scrollbar should appear. If I increase datagrid column width - only horizontal scrollbar for this datagrid should appear.

What blocks me:

When I increase datagrid column width - it resizes its datagrid and '**Outer**' horizontal scrollbar appears instead of '**Inner1**' that stays inactive.

In fact, in my app I have window with frame control. Frame loads page with custom content and page size may be larger than window size. Frame control is wrapped with ScrollViewer. Page contains some DataGrids wrapped with scrollviewers to show horizontal scrollbar when column width is changed even if there is no rows in datagrid.
So when I'm increasing datagrid column width, it resizes datagrid -> datagrid resizes entire page -> scrollviewer that wrapps frame appears.
Is it possible to disable datagrid resize when column width is changed?

Answer (score -1):

**It seems as though since they are nested within the same grid row they were using the top-level scroll viewer for both. This is a fix, but not sure if it is what you want.**

```
  <Window x:Class="NestedScrollViewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Outer" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column A" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column B" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Inner2" Grid.Row="1" CanContentScroll="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column С" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Column В" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```